# NSIS nsDialog How to check status of a RadioButton outside of page

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I'm trying to create a custom page via nsDialog, with radio buttons that then affect a section further on.  The issue I have is that the values do not seem to propagate beyond the `CustomPage` funtion, seen in the example below:

```
Var RADIO_APPLE
Var RADIO_BANANA

Function CustomPage
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 0 100% 10u "Apple"
    Pop $RADIO_APPLE
  ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 20 100% 10u "Banana"
    Pop $RADIO_BANANA

  ${NSD_Check} $RADIO_APPLE
  nsDialogs::Show

  ${NSD_GetState} $RADIO_APPLE $0
  ${NSD_GetState} $RADIO_BANANA $1
  MessageBox MB_OK "Apple $0 Banana $1"

FunctionEnd


Section "-CustomSection"
  ${NSD_GetState} $RADIO_APPLE $0
  ${NSD_GetState} $RADIO_BANANA $1
  MessageBox MB_OK "Apple $0 Banana $1"

SectionEnd
```

This is obviously a gist, ignoring the includes and other pages, but when I build the full version of this I see

```
Apple 1 Banana 0
```

on the message box raised inside `CustomPage`, but see

```
Apple 0 Banana 0
```

when the section is run.

I've read through https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NsDialogs_FAQ#How_to_easily_handle_radiobutton_selections and this solution gives me the same outcome.

Is there something I'm missing to make `$RADIO_*` available in the section?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store important long-lasting state in the registers, especially in $0 because it is used by other pages and plug-ins. The components page for example uses $0 in one of the callback functions.

Your checkbox handles on the other hand are only used on that page so you could use $1 and $2.

The other issue is, you can't rely on reading control data after `nsDialogs::Show` returns. You are supposed to use the leave callback to validate and store user input.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Page Custom MyCreate MyLeave
Page InstFiles

Var Apple
Var Banana

Function .onInit
  StrCpy $Banana 1 ; Make banana the default
FunctionEnd


Function MyCreate
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0
  ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 0 100% 10u "Apple"
    Pop $1
  ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 0 20 100% 10u "Banana"
    Pop $2

  ${NSD_SetState} $1 $Apple
  ${NSD_SetState} $2 $Banana
  nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyLeave
  ${NSD_GetState} $1 $Apple
  ${NSD_GetState} $2 $Banana
FunctionEnd


Section "-CustomSection"
  MessageBox MB_OK "Apple $Apple Banana $Banana"
SectionEnd
```